# Redux state set object to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

i have initial state like:

```
let initialState = {
   items: [
      {
        name: 'a'
      },
      {
        name: 'b'
      }
   ],
   otherItems: []
}
```

i'm trying to copy items and make it otherItems so otherItems will be same with items in case `SET_OBJECT`

```
case: SET_OBJECT
  return {
   ...state, 
   otherItems: items
  }
```

i tried this but not worked. I'm getting error  **items is not defined**

Comment: Could you please post your full reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should be like this

```
case: SET_OBJECT: 
  return {
   ...state, 
   otherItems: initialState.items
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct `items` use `state.items`